# Change ODBC-Connection in Access 2007

Tags: odbc, ms-access-2007

I hava a Pass-Through sql-query in access which queries my mysql-db.

My current ODBC connection for the query is defined as follows:

```
ODBC;UID=access_frontend; PWD=hello@world; DSN=my_db_test;
```

If I change my ODBC connection from my test to my normal DB

```
ODBC;UID=access_frontend; PWD=hello@world; DSN=my_db;
```

If I save my changes and restart again, Access has changed it back to `my_db_test`.

Is there any place where I can globally change my ODBC connection?`

Comment: How are you changing the connection? Are you sure there is no start-up code?

Comment: The issue was the startup code! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not get this problem changing in code or manually. You can change the connection through VBA:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
''dbQSQLPassThrough = 112
For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    If qdf.Type = dbQSQLPassThrough Then
        Debug.Print qdf.connect
        qdf.connect = "ODBC;filedsn=z:\docs\test.dsn;"
        Debug.Print qdf.connect
    End If
Next
```

You will notice that the passthrough query illustrated refers to:

```
filedsn=z:\docs\test.dsn;
```

This is another easy way of changing the connection, just change the DSN, in the above case, you could just edit the file `test.dsn`.